# Labels for my solutions with R programming function command

Tags: r, function, return, label

Just learning R-programming and am trying to find a way to include a description with the solutions I get from my function. For example, if i solve for Area, I want the function to say "Area = 2", rather than just "2". I've tried the print/paste command, but for the life of me all the different variations I tried wont work with the function command. Perhaps I'm missing something simple?

```
    TrapGeo<-function(b,m,y){ 
A=((b+m*y)/y)
#Flow Area
P=(b+2*y*(sqrt(1+(m^2))))
#Wetted Perimeter
R=A/P
#Hydraulic Radius
B=b+2*m*y
#Top Water Width
D=A/B
#Hydraulic Depth
output=c(A, P, R, B, D)
return(output) 
print(paste("Flow Area =", A)) 
print(paste("Wetted Perimeter =", P)) 
print(paste("Hydraulic Radius =", R)) 
print(paste("Top Water Width =", B)) 
print(paste("Hydraulic Depth =", D)) 
}
```

As of right now, the function returns only the output as I have asked it to, but I want to include a label for the solutions which is what I am attempting to do with the print(paste()) portion at the bottom.

Comment: `return()` needs to be the last line in your function. All the `print()` commands are not executed as it is now.

Comment: When you say you want the labels to be returned, do you mean printed after running the function, or do you mean accessible after the function has run, like in the case of return(output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **return()** in this case is kind of like clearing the object(s). So printing "A" after using return won't do as expected. Instead, if you'd like to print "output" before printing the other statements, use print(output); then have the last line be return(), while using **invisible(output)** inside that function so that "output" doesn't print twice.

Try this:

```
TrapGeo<-function(b,m,y){ 
  A=((b+m*y)/y)
  #Flow Area
  P=(b+2*y*(sqrt(1+(m^2))))
  #Wetted Perimeter
  R=A/P
  #Hydraulic Radius
  B=b+2*m*y
  #Top Water Width
  D=A/B
  #Hydraulic Depth
  output=c(A, P, R, B, D)
  print(output)
  print(paste("Flow Area =", A)) 
  print(paste("Wetted Perimeter =", P)) 
  print(paste("Hydraulic Radius =", R)) 
  print(paste("Top Water Width =", B)) 
  print(paste("Hydraulic Depth =", D))
  return(invisible(output))
}

TrapGeo(1,2,3)
```

Output:

```
[1]  2.3333333 14.4164079  0.1618526 13.0000000  0.1794872
[1] "Flow Area = 2.33333333333333"
[1] "Wetted Perimeter = 14.4164078649987"
[1] "Hydraulic Radius = 0.161852616489741"
[1] "Top Water Width = 13"
[1] "Hydraulic Depth = 0.179487179487179"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do to have access to the data calculated in the function, including the formatted output:

```
TrapGeo <- function( b, m, y)
{ 
    # Flow Area:
    A = ( ( b + m * y ) / y )
    # Wetted Perimeter:
    P = ( b + 2 * y * ( sqrt( 1 + ( m^2 ) ) ) )
    # Hydraulic Radius:
    R = A / P
    # Top Water Width:
    B = b + 2 * m * y
    # Hydraulic Depth:
    D = A / B

    # ready to print 
    output <- paste("Flow Area = ", A, "\n",
        "Wetted Perimeter = ", P, "\n",
        "Hydraulic Radius = ", R, "\n",
        "Top Water Width = ", B,  "\n",
        "Hydraulic Depth = ", D, "\n", sep = "" )

    # return both numbers and the formatted output
    return( list( c( A, P, R, B, D ), output ) )
}
```

Now you can assign values to any variable using your function which also makes sure nothing is printed on screen:

```
x <- TrapGeo( 1, 2, 3 )
```

Now or at any later stage, you can show the formatted data on the screen (or save it to a file) using list notation and the `cat()` commend:

```
cat( x[[2]] )
Flow Area = 2.33333333333333
Wetted Perimeter = 14.4164078649987
Hydraulic Radius = 0.161852616489741
Top Water Width = 13
Hydraulic Depth = 0.179487179487179
```

At the same time, you have access to the data as numbers for further use:

```
x[[1]][3]
[1] 0.1618526
```